# How do I get the text to change?

Tags: processing

I'm currently doing an assignment using processing, and I can't seem to figure out how to change the text.

The assignment basically revolves around a kite that moves, and after each 'step' that it we make, the next 'step' should appear. E.g. i am to provide a screen that resembles a rooftop at the bottom of the screen with an electric pole to the left. As the code runs, there is no kite, but as i click and then drag it'll appear.

So i guess after each movement that happens, the text at the bottom of the scgreen should update with the next step.

The text goes from: “Press, then drag, the mouse in the brown area (rooftop) to begin” *to* “Drag and then release in the blue area (sky)” and so forth

Thanks guys

Comment: What is the difference between the two text? And what is the conditions to make the text change?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the third paragraph, but I'm assuming you want text to appear after the mouse is released

You can use `mouseReleased()` to generate the text at mouse position when the mouse is released

```
void mouseReleased () {
  text("Press, then drag, the mouse in the brown area (rooftop) to begin” to “Press, then drag, the mouse in the brown area (rooftop) to begin", mouseX, mouseY)
}
```